# Swagger - How to reuse a set of parameters?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I know that you can use `$ref` to reuse query parameters definition over different api calls but is it possible to do so with a set of parameters?
I have let's say 5 parameters I use in every call and if I need to add one, I will create its definition and add its reference everywhere, but if I could define a set of parameters called `filters` that I would put as a parameter for every call, I would have just to add this new parameter in this set definition.

Is it possible to do and if so, how?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005105/swagger-openapi-use-ref-to-pass-a-reusable-defined-parameter

Comment: Yes, as I said I know I can define parameters that I can link to other places in the swagger file. But I would like to define a list of parameters that I can reference elsewhere.