# Swagger ui - call parameters from components

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I use swagger ui with swaggerapi/swagger-ui docker image. I try to use parameters defined in components in one of my paths, but that doesn't work. Where is the problem ?

In my index.yaml file

```
components:
  ...
  parameters:
    Pagination:
    - in: query
      name: page
      schema:
        type: integer
        required: false
      description: The page to go to
    - in: query
      name: per_page
      schema:
        type: integer
        required: false
      description: The number of items per page
  ...
```

In my path file

```
parameters:
  $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/parameters/Pagination'
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Related: [Swagger/OpenAPI - use $ref to pass a reusable defined parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27005105/113116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI lets you `$ref` individual parameters, but not a group of parameters. So if you have several common parameters, you need to create separate definitions for them in the `components/parameters` section. Also, `required` is a parameter attribute and not a schema attribute:

```yaml
components:
  parameters:
    pageParam:          # <-----
      in: query
      name: page
      schema:
        type: integer
      required: false   # <-----
      description: The page to go to
    perPageParam:       # <-----
      in: query
      name: per_page
      schema:
        type: integer
      required: false   # <-----
      description: The number of items per page
```

Then, in your path file, use:

```yaml
parameters:
  - $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/parameters/pageParam'
  - $ref: '../index.yaml#/components/parameters/perPageParam'
```