# Re-usable parameters in open api specification

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

I have an endpoint which takes an X-Request-ID header.  This is described as:

```
parameters:
    - in: header
      name: X-Request-ID
      schema:
        type: string
        format: uuid
      required: true
```

However, if I have ten endpoints that take this header, do I have to keep repeating this or is there anyway I can get some re-use?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger/OpenAPI - use $ref to pass a reusable defined parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005105/swagger-openapi-use-ref-to-pass-a-reusable-defined-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Helen's comment, you can achieve some reuse by defining `X-Request-ID` as a [Parameter Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject) in the [Parameters Definitions Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameters-definitions-object), then reference it (by using a [Reference Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#referenceObject)) in the `parameters` field of each [Path Item Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#path-item-object) to denote that it's applicable to all operations under the path.