# How to specify same path params at a single place for multiple endpoints in a swagger.yaml file

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have  3 end points `start`, `stop`, `status` that looked like this

```
paths:
  /users:
    # other endpoint
  /containers/{vendorID}/{pluginID}/{artifactID}/start:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: vendorID
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: pluginID
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: artifactId
          required: true
          type: string
      get:
        # get related stuff
  /containers/{vendorID}/{pluginID}/{artifactID}/stop:
    parameters:
        - in: path
          name: vendorID
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: pluginID
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: artifactId
          required: true
          type: string
    get:
      # get related stuff
  /containers/{vendorID}/{pluginID}/{artifactID}/status:
    parameters:
        - in: path
          name: vendorID
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: pluginID
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: artifactId
          required: true
          type: string
    get:
      # get related stuff
```

All the endpoints `start`, `stop`, `status` has the same parameters but i ended up duplicating it at 3 different places.  I am using swagger 2.0 but openApi3.0 is also welcome.  Is there a way that I can specify these path params at one place and use it at other places ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can define those parameters in the global `components.parameters` section and reference them using `$ref` as shown in the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286746/113116).

Comment: All definitions can be found here.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/2.0.md